# MySQL Group By with Distinct

Tags: mysql

I have a dynamic table (from subquery):

```
col1 | col2
-----------
 14  | 1000
 14  | 2000
 14  | 3000
 15  | 1000
 15  | 2000
```

I want to group result by col1, but with distinct col2 value:

```
col1 | col2
-----------
 14  | 1000
 15  | 2000
```

Is it possible?

*additional info*:

- col2 is ordered by ASC
- col1 values is not important, can be removed from result table
- number of rows = number of col1 unique values

Comment: Why those values for col2?

Comment: Your logic is not clear.  What happened to the records (14, 2000) and (15, 2000)?  What would happen if you had (14, 3000)?

Comment: @LoztInSpace in fact i need only col2 values and count of unique col1 values. themselves col1 values is not important at all. 1000 | 2 and 2000 | 2 will be fine too

Comment: Sorry mate, but I still have no idea what you're trying to do.  If you want distinct col 2 then just select distinct col2.  Unless you mean select count2, count(distinct col1) from table group by col2

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this one:

```
select DISTINCT(col2), col1 from tablename group by col1
```

Comment: both col2 values are 1000

Comment: Yes..it will take the first record from the query so that both col2 values are 1000. You have to something else to check as a condition in the query otherwise it will take the first record from the fetched rows.